# Mysql 5.7 Table 'performance_schema.metadata_locks' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I faced metadata lock problem and found nice solution:

http://mysql.wisborg.dk/2014/01/13/who-holds-the-metadata-lock-mysql-5-7-3-brings-help/

I did:

```
UPDATE setup_consumers SET ENABLED = 'YES' WHERE NAME = 'global_instrumentation';
```

and:

```
UPDATE setup_instruments SET ENABLED = 'YES' WHERE NAME = 'wait/lock/metadata/sql/mdl';
```

But unfortunately I can't see table named "metadata_locks" in my "performance_schema" DB...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What have those two updates to do with pure existence of `metadata_locks` table? Do you get any ERROR doing the update?

Comment: It looks like an update from an earlier version without running `mysql_upgrade` (metadata_locks is new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. It was upgrade from earlier version. I had to run **mysql_upgrade** and it rebuilded/created all necessary tables.